# Powershell: The access to the certificate store returns an empty EnhancedKeyUsageList

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

When I run the following script line on my Windows 7 32bit (PS version 3.0) I get an empty EnhancedKeyUsageList (I see only empty curly brackets {}).

On a Windows 10 machine with PS 5.x I get the right result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Format-List -Property *
```

Comment: Well your command, as currently provided is invalid syntax (`Get-ChildItemItem`). Please share the _actual_ code in order to be better assisted

Comment: Thank you, it was only a typo in this post, the issue is still there.

Comment: [Certificates that have an empty `EnhancedKeyUsageList` can be used for all purposes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/providers/get-childitem-for-certificate?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

A certificate with EnhancedKeyUsage set to `ALL` will have this as empty if queried . Open the certificate store via MMC and check the same for the certificate you are getting EKU as null.